# Defining a config model with some defaults

Tags: typescript

In Python the de-facto ways of defining "data classes" are either by using the built-in dataclass module, or (for more power), the pydantic library.

Both of these solve the same thing: giving the ability to define and use data-centric classes (classes with little or no functionality, only meant to store and validate data).

An example of pydantic would be:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int # required
    name = 'John Doe' # optional with default
    friends: List[int] = [] # optional, defaults to empty array
```

I could expand this by adding validator functions to check for minimum field length etc.

I'm looking for something similar with TypeScript. This is what I've learned so far:

- interfaces would be the obvious choice, but they only let you define the data *structure* , you can't use interfaces to set defaults
- I've looked into zod but it looks like it's more for validating "unknown" data. I'm not able to use the `infer` functionality to generate a type that correctly returns default data

I know there are also tricks like create a separate function for implementing "overrides":

```js
export type User = {
    id: number;
    name?: string;
};

export function generateUser(
    props: User
): User {
    const defaults = {
        name: 'peter',
    };
    return {
        ...defaults,
        ...props
    };
}
```

But this seems a little convoluted to me since I have to define the "default fields" twice (both in the type and in the function).
It also has the drawback of telling typescript that `name` is optional and might not exist. I want to always exist, but filled with a default value if nothing else was specified.

Does TypeScript offer a more elegant way of defining defaults?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but in TypeScript, you can use some helper generics to modify any given type. For example, you are looking for a concrete type where `name` is always defined, but not required in the function input.

I would define the types like so:

1. Define a separate type for the input where properties may be optional
2. Let typescript determine the output type of the `generateUser` function
3. If you want to use the `User` type in other parts of your application, you can obtain the type by using `ReturnType<typeof generateUser>`.

```
type UserInput = {
  id: number;
  name?: string;
};

export function generateUser (
  input: UserInput
) {
  return {
    name: 'peter',
    ...input
  };
}

type User = ReturnType<typeof generateUser>;
```

Another solution would be to do it the other way around. We define the `User` type as it would come out of the `generateUser` function, but modify it for the `input` arguments.

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

type UserInput = Partial<Pick<User, 'name'>> & Omit<User, 'name'>;

export function generateUser (
  input: UserInput,
): User {
  return {
    name: 'peter',
    ...input
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks! I guess I was hoping there would be a more "compact" way of doing this. I'm used to doing all of this in 3 lines of code. Here I have to "touch" the `name` attr 2 or 3 times.

Using Partial is a neat trick tho, thanks!!